# How to add a timestamp and a userstamp column that is triggered by any edit done in the corresponding row

Tags: timestamp

I am trying to create a code that will create a timestamp, noting the time during which a particular row in my sheet has been updated and also a userstamp, noting who made that last update.  I have read through numerous posts and tried following certain video guides, however nothing seems to address this particular issue as it relates to editing a row.  Any suggestions for resources or guides?  Thank you!

Comment: Which programming language are you using? When you say "row", are you using a database? If yes which one? (Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Comment: I'm trying to do this for a Google Sheet